# powershell-script to read login and logouts from EventLog

Tags: powershell, event-log

At my work we use Windows. I want to track my logins and logouts, to for example create a time report.

This is what I have googled and guessed so far, by inspecting the event log.

```
Get-EventLog security | `
Where-Object {$_.TimeGenerated -gt '7/02/19 05:44'} | `  
Where-Object {($_.EventId -eq 4648) -or ($_.EventId -eq 4634 -and $_.Message.Contains('Logon Type:          3')) } | `
Select-Object TimeGenerated,InstanceID,Message | `
Group TimeGenerated,InstanceID
```

My problem is that I get a whole lot of entries where I clearly havent been at my desk. Can I somehow distinct human login/logouts from all the magicmojo thats happening when Im not there.

It doesnt need to be reading from event log either, as long as I get what I want

Answer (score 0):

here's is one way to do what i think you want. i don't have any `4634` or `4648` events - only `4624`, so i added that to the list to check for. this uses the `$env:USERNAME` & `$env:COMPUTERNAME` environment vars to get the target user name & system name.

it builds a `filterhashtable` to get the info, then a splat to hold the parameters for the `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet call.

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

# there REALLY otta be a way to get this list programmatically
$LogonTypeTable = [ordered]@{
    '0' = 'System'
    '2' = 'Interactive'
    '3' = 'Network'
    '4' = 'Batch'
    '5' = 'Service'
    '6' = 'Proxy'
    '7' = 'Unlock'
    '8' = 'NetworkCleartext'
    '9' = 'NewCredentials'
    '10' = 'RemoteInteractive'
    '11' = 'CachedInteractive'
    '12' = 'CachedRemoteInteractive'
    '13' = 'CachedUnlock'
    }
$EventLevelTable = [ordered]@{
    LogAlways = 0
    Critical = 1
    Error = 2
    Warning = 3
    Informational = 4
    Verbose = 5
    }

$TargetUserName = $env:USERNAME
$WantedLogonTypes = @(2, 3, 10, 11)
$AgeInDays = 30
$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$AgeInDays)

$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$GWE_FilterHashTable = @{
    Logname = 'Security'
    ID = 4624, 4634, 4648
    StartTime = $StartDate
    #Level  = 2
    }
$GWE_Params = @{
    FilterHashtable = $GWE_FilterHashTable
    ComputerName = $ComputerName
    MaxEvents = 100
    }
$RawLogonEventList = Get-WinEvent @GWE_Params

$LogonEventList = foreach ($RLEL_Item in $RawLogonEventList)
    {
    $UserName = $RLEL_Item.Properties[5].Value
    $LogonTypeID = $RLEL_Item.Properties[8].Value
#<#
    # if you want all logins, use the other version of this IF block
    if (($LogonTypeID -in $WantedLogonTypes) -and
        ($UserName -eq $TargetUserName))
#>
<#
    # this will get all accounts
    if ($LogonTypeID -in $WantedLogonTypes)
#>
        {
        $DaysAgo = [math]::Round(([datetime]::Now - $RLEL_Item.TimeCreated).TotalDays, 0)
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            LogName = $RLEL_Item.LogName
            EventID = $RLEL_Item.Id
            TimeCreated = $RLEL_Item.TimeCreated
            DaysAgo = $DaysAgo
            UserName = $RLEL_Item.Properties[5].Value
            LogonTypeID = $LogonTypeID
            LogonTypeName = $LogonTypeTable[$LogonTypeID.ToString()]
            }
        }
    }

$LogonEventList |
    Sort-Object -Property TimeCreated
```

output ...

```
LogName       : Security
EventID       : 4624
TimeCreated   : 2019-06-22 11:10:35 AM
DaysAgo       : 10
UserName      : [MyUserName]
LogonTypeID   : 2
LogonTypeName : Interactive
```

there is only the one in the last 30 days for me. [*grin*]

Comment: Clearly you are in a different league that me when it comes to ps. Iv learned alot just lookin at this, thnks alot. But  with this script I cant find my logouts at all and I think I get doublettes on the logins 4624. (PS. I needed to set up MaxEvents to get more than the last hours activity). The script is great, but I still cant get only human logins and logouts :/... Ive tried a few experiments with 4634 as well but it seems to get logged many times outside office times and also again and again when Im already logged out

Comment: @Cowborg - arg! i only have the `4624` logins for my account. when i remove the filters and look at `$RawLogonEventList`, i only see my account and the system account that have logins i the last 30 days. ///// thank you for the kind words! i enjoy _trying_ to help ... [*grin*]